# What are the 24/7 bus lines of Bangkok?

Tags: thailand

I desire to learn what are all the 24/7 bus lines of Bangkok.

The [current transit bangkok table](https://www.transitbangkok.com/bangkok_buses.html) lists the following lines as 24(/7) lines:

```
2, 4, 22
23, 25, 29
34, 59, 76
91, 145, 203
```

But I fear the table might be slightly outdated because I myself took line 60 (Petchaburi-RamKhamaeng) several times between 01:00-05:00.

Also,

- I think line 40 (expanded version ; Chinatown-RamKhamaeng) has recently turned 24/7
- I recall taking line 168 around Klong Toey area (which starts from Klong Toey bus depot) around 03:30 but I might confuse with either 01:00 or 05:00.

**What are the 24/7 bus lines of Bangkok?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the above list is updated but I testify from experience, as far as I recall, that indeed line 60 and line 93 are almost daily operational between 01:00 to 05:00.

It is indeed likely that line 40 (which is a very demanded line going through most of the central parts of the city) would start working until after 24:00 or somewhat before 04:00, especially in midst week (no holidays); BTW in 2020 a new fleet of line 40 buses was added (it is a very demanded line as well).

<sub>After all, with the ultra dynamic Bangokian economy it's often hard to guarantee what is generally correct.</sub>